# Browser / address bar when scrolling mobile browsers by click

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, scroll

I’m struggling against a scrolling issue with mobile browsers on both iOS and Android. Expected behaviour is the top browser bar disappearing or getting minimized as soon as I start scrolling the page down by swiping my finger to the top.

Unfortunately the behaviour of the browser bar is completely different when the scrolling isn’t done by hand but by clicking a link to target an anchor. While the page scrolls to the anchor as expected, nothing at all happens to the browser bar. As long as I don’t swipe with my finger, the bar is staying in place without any changes.

I tried several settings in meta/vieport and javascript like this without success:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

How can I make the browser to behave the same way, no matter whether I’m scrolling with a swipe or a click? I can live quite well with the differences among browsers, but would appreciate very much if the same browser would act always the same way in both situations.

Thanks for any hint

Ralf

Comment: I wonder if this blog page may be able to help you: https://www.hesslerdesign.com/blog/user-experience-2/why-window-scrollto-is-harmful-for-mobile-websites/

Comment: Thanks acarlstein, but it doesn’t change anything. The page oiffers basically my shown standard code with a few extending lines that do not solve my problem. Hard times I fear.